# Java: How to convert items to string file?

Tags: java, android

I have this java code. I want to convert items in string file

```
package com.fff.c;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    //private static final String[] items = new String[] {
    //         "My Uploaded Videos", "My Tagged Videos", "Page Videos", "Friends Videos",
    //             "Group Videos", "Explore Mode", "News feed Videos", "Timeline Videos",
    //             "Saved Videos", "Downloaded Videos"
    //};

    private static final int[] icons = new int[] {
        R.drawable.ic_action_pic, R.drawable.ic_tagged, R.drawable.ic_video, R.drawable.ic_friend,
            R.drawable.ic_group, R.drawable.ic_explore, R.drawable.ic_timeline,
            R.drawable.ic_timeline, R.drawable.ic_like, R.drawable.ic_saved
    };

    private ListView listView = null;

    private HomeAdapter adapter = new HomeAdapter();

    public HomeFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (!(context instanceof AppCompatActivity))
            return;
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar == null)
            return;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof AppCompatActivity))
            return;
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar == null)
            return;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        boolean showAd = false;

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                fragment = GraphVideoListFragment.newInstance("me/videos/uploaded", "user_videos");
                showAd = true;
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = GraphVideoListFragment.newInstance("me/videos/tagged", "user_videos");
                showAd = true;
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = new PageListFragment();
                break;

            case 3:
                fragment = new FriendsListFragment();
                break;

            case 4:
                fragment = new GroupListFragment();
                break;

            case 5:
                fragment = new ExplorerFragment();
                showAd = true;
                break;

            case 6:
                fragment = PageVideoListFragment.newInstance("https://mobile.facebook.com/stories.php", "See more stories");
                break;

            case 7:
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                fragment = PageVideoListFragment.newInstance(profile.getLinkUri().toString(), "Show more");
                break;

            case 8:
                fragment = new SavedVideosListFragment();
                break;

            case 9:
                fragment = new DownloadedVideosFragment();
                break;

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack("uploaded videos");
            ft.commit();
        }

        if (showAd)
            showFullScreenAd();

    }

    private void showFullScreenAd() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity == null)
            return;

        ((MainActivity) activity).showFullScreenAd();
    }

    private class HomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = null;
            if (position == 0 && convertView != null && convertView.getId() == R.id.item_profile) {
                view = convertView;
            } else if (position == 0){
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_profile, parent, false);
            }

            if (position > 0 && convertView != null && convertView.getId() == R.id.item) {
                view = convertView;
            } else if (position > 0) {
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            }

            if (position == 0) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
                textView.setText((CharSequence) getItem(position));
                if (profile != null) {
                    ProfilePictureView pictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePictureView);
                    pictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
                    pictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.SMALL);
                }
            } else {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
                textView.setText((CharSequence) getItem(position));

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                iv.setImageResource(icons[position]);
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

want it work in **strings.xml**

### String Resources

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">videofc</string>

    <string name="facebook_app_id">10706673196552</string>
    <string name="title_activity_settings">Settings</string>

    <string name="logout">Logout of facebook</string>
    <string name="rate">Rate App</string>
    <string name="download_folder">Download folder</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have written many answer. Want them to be upvoted. Thank you. Sarcasm off: not going to happen.

Comment: Sorry, SO doesn't work this way. We help you solving your problems, we don't solve them for you! Meaning: please post the code you have written so far; and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Define a string array in **Strings.xml**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name="my_videos">
            <item>my uploaded</item>
            <item>My Tagged Videos</item>
            <item>Friends Videos</item>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

To get this array in your java file:

```
String[] my_videos= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_videos);
```

Comment: Funny that is. But not sure if he gets the pun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Array resource. Example from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then in code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<resources>\n");
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
System.out.print("<string name=\"" +items[i] + "\">text_string</string>\n");
}
System.out.print("</resources>");
```